# Problems accessing one share from a Synology NAS by some users

Tags: permissions, network-shares, nas, synology-diskstation

I have a Synology NAS (DS218, DSM 6.2) that's set up and working fine. Several members of the family can access the NAS, and Plex is set up also. Using my account (I'm a member of the administrator group on the NAS), I can access all shares: my home; homes; music; videos; photos.

Other users (who are in the same groups except not administrator) can access all shares *except* photos: they can connect but see nothing within it. This includes Plex: although it sees and plays all media from the music and videos shared folders, it sees nothing within the photos share.

All the settings within the Synology DSM Control Panel for the shared folders seem to be identical for the different shares, except that, when I go to Control Panel > Shared folders > Advanced permissions in DSM for each of these shares, I noticed that the music share has an extra section on that tab, called "Advanced Share Permissions", although this option is disabled.

I've looked at the permissions for the different user groups and they also seem to be identical. The issue is visible across several different device types (Windows, Roku boxes, web clients).

Interestingly, if I add Plex (for example) to the administrator group then the share becomes accessible. But, obviously, I don't want to give admin rights to everyone.

If I inspect a file within each directory using File Station on the web DSM interface then I see different Permissions tabs. In the music share, for example, I see a list of users and groups, and can edit the permissions for that group.

[image: Music permissions]

In the photos share, I see a classic *nix grid of permissions for Owner, Group and Others / Read, Write and Execute.

[image: Photo permissions]

Can anyone suggest what's going on with this share and how I might get it working like the others?

Answer (score 0):

I've eventually decided to work around the problem: I created a new share and copied the files over. The new share seems to work fine, so it's obviously a problem with the old share. Which is still odd but at least my family (and Plex!) can now access all files on the NAS.